# Wrong location within 302 http redirect using spring cloud gateway

Tags: redirect, gateway, togglz

Pushing toggle button changes state of feature successfully but page is redirected to under gateway service endpoint what we  are not expecting.

We are using togglz libraries below

`org.togglz:togglz-spring-boot-starter:4.4.0`

`org.togglz:togglz-spring-security:4.4.0`

`org.togglz:togglz-console:4.4.0`

`com.github.heneke.thymeleaf:thymeleaf-extras-togglz:2.0.1.RELEASE`

We are triggering /togglz-console/index endpoint via spring cloud gateway .
Pushing toggle button changes state of feature successfully but page is redirected to under gateway service endpoint what we  are not expecting.
We are expecting redirection to initial gateway endpoint.
Now it looks like

`gateway-url/togglz-console/index`

`gateway-url/togglz-console/edit`

`302 location service-url/togglz-console/edit`